# newRawData.forEach is not a function in ui-grid

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I search for this error but not able to fix it.Am new to angular.Dont know exactly whats going wrong.

Html:

```
<div class="row gridContainer" ng-controller="tripsGridController">
        <div ui-i18n="{{::selectedLanguageName}}">
            <div ui-grid="gridOptionsTrips" ui-grid-selection ui-grid-resize-columns ui-grid-move-columns ></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Angular code:

```
$scope.gridOptionsTrips = {};
        $scope.gridDataSourceTrips = [];
        var ROW_HEIGHT = 30;
      //  to show data on Grid
        $scope.gridOptionsTrips = {
            enableRowSelection: true,
            enableRowHeaderSelection: true,
            enableSorting: true,
            multiSelect: false,
            rowHeight: ROW_HEIGHT,
            virtualizationThreshold: 10,
            fastWatch: false,
            enableHorizontalScrollbar: uiGridConstants.scrollbars.NEVER,
            data: 'gridDataSourceTrips',
            appScopeProvider: $scope,
            showColumnMenu: true,
            enableSelectAll: false,
            noUnselect: true,
            enableCellSelection: true,
            rowTemplate: '<div ng-click=\"grid.appScope.onTripsGridRowClick(row)\" ng-repeat=\"(colRenderIndex, col) in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.uid\" class=\"ui-grid-cell\" ng-class=\"{ \'ui-grid-row-header-cell\': col.isRowHeader }\" ui-grid-cell></div>'
        };

 $scope.onTripsGridRowClick = function (row) {
            $scope.gridApi.selection.selectRow(row.entity);
        };

        $scope.gridColDefsTrips = function () {
            var idTemplate = '<div></div>';
            var sTemplate = '<div></div>';
            var speedTemplate = '<div></div>';
            var directionTemplate = '<div></div>';
            var timeTemplate = '<div></div>';
            var kmCounterTemplate = '<div></div>';
            var driverNameTemplate = '<div></div>';
            return [
                  { name: "CARDRIVER", displayName: "CARDRIVER", field: 'UserId', cellTemplate: idTemplate, enableColumnMenu: false, headerCellFilter: 'translate', width: 150, showInColumnFilter: true },
                  { name: 'STARTEND', displayName: 'STARTEND', field: 'Departure.DateTime', cellTemplate: idTemplate, width: 70, enableColumnMenu: false, headerCellFilter: 'translate', showInColumnFilter: true },
                  { name: 'STARTEND', displayName: 'STARTEND', field: 'Destination.DateTime',cellTemplate: idTemplate, enableColumnMenu: false, headerCellFilter: 'translate', width: 80, showInColumnFilter: true },
                  { name: 'TRIPLENGTH', displayName: 'TRIPLENGTH', field: 'Distance', cellTemplate: idTemplate, enableColumnMenu: false, headerCellFilter: 'translate', width: 150, showInColumnFilter: true }
            ];
        };
        $scope.gridDataSourceTrips = tripsDetailsService.GetAllTripsByWeek('2014-01-10', '2014-01-14', 1, 20);
        $scope.gridOptionsTrips.columnDefs = $scope.gridColDefsTrips();
```

Comment: I think this is known issue as mentioned [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/issues/4077). The issue is with the declaration of Array inside the script  where data:{} was used instead of data:[].  You may want to use the approach [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/issues/3677) . Let us know if this works.